# Clarifications about pointers in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

Here I have some lines of code I have problems with :

```
struct Node 
{
String data;
Node * next;
};

struct List
{
Node * head;
};

static Node  * nouvNode (string word,Node *p = nullptr){
Node  *pNouv = new Node ;
pNouv->data =word;
pNouv->next = p;
return pNouv;
```

Alright so, here are my questions:

1) pNouv here is a pointer I created, pointed to a node. 
When I do `pNouv=>next=p`, does it mean my pointer in pNouv is pointing to the next node which pointer p points to too ? Or my pointer is pointed to a note which does have a pointer too which points to another node where P is pointed to the same way?

2) `static Node  * nouvNode (string word,Node *p = nullptr)`
This is a method to create a new node with a data in it, but why does it need to have "Node *p = nullptr" in parameter? 
When I create a node in my program, I do this `nouvNode(word, ls.head)` for example.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is soo confusing - **Or my pointer is pointed to a note which does have a pointer too which points to another node where P is pointed to the same way?** Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

1) `pNouv->next = p` means that the struct member `next` in the struct pointed to by `pNouv` is set to point to the same thing as `p`. So there's a block of memory. `pNouv` points to that block of memory. Somewhere within that block of memory you place the address from `p`.

2) the `= nullptr` addition makes that parameter optional. You could validly just call `nouvNode(word)` and you'd receive a node with the value of `word` placed into it which did not point to anything as the next node.

Comment: Right okay i understand, so next is a structure pointed to p you say.
But isn't p a pointer? 
For me, next is a structure pointed to the same memory location as where points p too.

which one is it? Does it point to p, or to the same location pointer p points too?

Comment: You're right; it was a poorly-written answer. I've hopefully improved it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 pNouv->next=p
```

As per my understandings if you execute above statement `pNouv` node starts pointing to `p` node, which is nothing but `NULL`. So above code statement is equivalent to

```
pNouv=>next=NULL;
```

2)  `static Node * nouvNode (string word,Node *p = nullptr)`

Passing `Node *p = nullptr` as 2nd parameter is optional.
You just need the `word`. You can always create a new node in the body of the function and traverse from the head and then eventually position the newly created node at the desired location.